# Jboss AS7 - module deployment - java.lang.IllegalAccessError

Tags: jboss7.x

Please let me know why do I get the below error when deploying in the Jboss AS7. This error thrown when deploying the .ear and I have used modules. However, when I deploy the ear with the libraries in the lib it is deploying without any errors.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.apache.xerces.parsers.ObjectFactory from class org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source) [xercesImpl-2.8.1.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_38]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_38]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27) [rt.jar:1.6.0_38]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) [rt.jar:1.6.0_38]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355) [rt.jar:1.6.0_38]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308) [rt.jar:1.6.0_38]
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.NewInstance.newInstance(NewInstance.java:51) [rt.jar:1.6.0_38]
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.loadClass(XMLReaderFactory.java:187) [rt.jar:1.6.0_38]
    at org.xml.sax.helpers.XMLReaderFactory.createXMLReader(XMLReaderFactory.java:180) [rt.jar:1.6.0_38]
```

Comment: Is that all the exception stack you have?